# Symfony2 MethodNotAllowedException

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to show MethodNotAllowedException but i dont get display message.
Reading API for MethodNotAllowedException class first param is array, second is message=null.
I try this:

```
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\MethodNotAllowedException;

 throw new MethodNotAllowedException(null, "Method is not allowed.");
```

and i try this:

```
throw new MethodNotAllowedException("Method is not allowed.");
retrurn new MethodNotAllowedException(array("POST"), "Method is not allowed.");
throw new MethodNotAllowedException(array('post','Test'));
```

When i sumbit form(post) i get this in url but no message for MethodNotAllowedException

> http://localhost/Symfony2/web/app_dev.php/admin/category/create?eshop_category[name]=asd&eshop_category[parent]=4&eshop_category[status]=1&eshop_category[description]=asd&eshop_category[_token]=E87mCc4lCG1nLgLDdNKi9oxiT7Ak0-UXhNYXZ5_0y3k

Answer (score -1):

```
throw new \Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\MethodNotAllowedException(array('method1', 'method2', '...'), 'N-A');
```

This way it works (and please don't ask why exception don't use use statement :)

Good Luck!